# How to create a dialog box on click of a Web Item in Confluence?

Tags: javascript, plugins, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am new to developing plugins in Confluence.
I have created a Plugin which is adding a Web-item “AAD Permissions” under Space permissions section of Confluence (attaching the screenshot for reference).
Now, on click of that Web item I need to open a dialog box with an input. Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks & Regards,
Preethi H R

Answer (score 0):

To have a Dialog item, you need to create:

1. Web Item or section (seems you did it)
2. Add AJS/AUI code or Struts Action to trigger Dialog

So you add either AJS JQuery based trigger now to the HTML tempate of this web item or create custom action on backend - https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/adding-a-custom-action-to-confluence/

Here are guides:

- Dialog component - https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/dialog-wizard-module/
- AUI/AJS - https://aui.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/dialog2.html